# Memory Access Violation Insert Struct Within Tree Struct C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a tree of structures and insert my data for the tree nodes into the structure which contains two data holders. My tree/data structures look as such:

```
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:

struct IndexEntry
{
    int acctID;   // (key) Account identifier
    long recNum;  // Record number
};

struct tree_node
{
    IndexEntry* entry;
    tree_node* left;
    tree_node* right;
};
tree_node* root;

public:
BinarySearchTree()
{
    root = NULL;
}

bool isEmpty() const { return root == NULL; }
void insert(int, int);
int search(int);
int treeSearch(tree_node*, int);
};
```

I am getting a memory access violation at this point in my insert function, and to be honest, this is the first time I'm attempting a tree of structures so I have no clue whether or not it is even a correct insert function to begin with. But here it is:

```
void BinarySearchTree::insert(int rNum, int aNum)
{
tree_node* t = new tree_node;
tree_node* parent;
t -> entry -> recNum = rNum; //right here I get a violation
t -> entry -> acctID = aNum; //but if I remove the assignments
t -> left = NULL;            //it gives me a violation further down
t -> right = NULL;
parent = NULL;

if (isEmpty())
    root = t;
else
{
    tree_node* current;
    current = root;
    // Find the Node's parent
    while (current)
    {
        parent = current; //This whole block will give me a memory violation
        if (t -> entry -> recNum > current -> entry -> recNum) 
            current = current -> right;
        else current = current -> left;
    }

    if (t -> entry -> recNum < parent -> entry -> recNum)
        parent -> left = t;
    else
        parent -> right = t;
}
}
```

Please refer to my comments in the second block of code for the locations of the memory access violations. I'm thinking there is something uninitialized within the code, but I don't really know where it would be or how to initialize it.

Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You never initialized `t->entry`.

Comment: Don't put spaces around `->`, it's not idiomatic.

Comment: Especially don't mix it with `>` operator. Looks like a train of arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dereferencing not initialized pointer. When you do this:

```
tree_node* t = new tree_node;
```

then compiler will execute default constructor which actually does nothing. `t->entry` is not assigned any value and contains garbage.

So later on when you dereference it with:

```
t -> entry -> recNum = rNum; //right here I get a violation
```

(`t -> entry ->` is dereference operation), you are getting Undefined Behaviour which in your case results in crash.

The solution is to initialize `t -> entry` before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize `t->entry`

```
tree_node *t = new tree_node;
t->entry = new IndexEntry;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `entry` pointer in `tree_node` is not initialized properly, it's a pointer and it isn't pointing to a valid object. You can initialize it in the constructor, and don't forget to delete it in the destructor.

```
struct tree_node 
{
    IndexEntry *entry;
    tree_node *left;
    tree_node *right;

    tree_node() :
        entry(new IndexEntry), // create a new entry object
        left(NULL), right(NULL)
    {}

    ~tree_node() 
    {
        delete entry; // release the memory when we're done
    }
};
```

In fact, I don't see why you need to create `IndexEntry` in the heap in the first place. It seems `entry` is part of `tree_node`, so you can simply "embed" it in `tree_node`:

```
struct tree_node
{
    IndexEntry entry; // not a pointer, but an object
    tree_node *left;
    tree_node *right;
};
```

Of course you need to use `.` when accessing the members of `entry`:

```
tree_node *t = new tree_node;
t->entry.recNum = rNum;
t->entry.acctID = aNum;
t->left = NULL;
t->right = NULL;
```